# Unable to Automate kendo dropdownlist in selenium webdriver using c#

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am unable to automate ken-do drop down-list in selenium web-driver using c# below mentioned HTML Script

```html
<kendo-dropdownlist _ngcontent-cuj-c4="" name="clientProgram" style="flex: 1 1 auto;" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" dir="ltr">
<span role="listbox" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" id="k-f98f1175-1311-49f2-b1bf-6a8ede866460" dir="ltr" readonly="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="d94ddcab-5292-44c5-ab1f-841d254481fc" aria-activedescendant="8b669b5d-7926-477b-9b0a-e920553a260a-0">                
<span class="k-input" unselectable="on">Select Program...</span>
<span class="k-select" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s"></span>
</span>
</span>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

I tried below mentioned code for automating,

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
IWebElement optionsList = getElement("xpath", "//span[contains(text(),'Select Program...')]");
action.MoveToElement(optionsList);
IList<IWebElement> options = getElements("xpath", "//*[contains(@class,'k-animation-container k-animation-container-shown')]");
                foreach (IWebElement option in options)
                {
                    if (option.Text.Equals("BAC"))
                    {
                        option.Click();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: There are no options in the dropdown HTML you posted. Are there supposed to be? You probably want to update the HTML once it's populated with the choices.

Comment: @JeffC : front end design in angular js and its not showing any dropdown option in HTML.. there is a kendodropdownlist and after that we have span

Comment: The options have to be exist somewhere in the DOM. We need the HTML of the options list to provide a locator.